# Store description of file in Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have requests from a number of my clients to supply a full list of files and what each of the files do (including a short description of business logic).  This forms part of the release notes that they require.

We develop ASP.NET websites and use **VisualSVN Server** to manage Subversion plus **TortoiseSVN** as a client. I have configured a pre-commit hook to force developers to add a description of why a file changed when they are trying to commit. However, this is specific to a revision of a file.

What I need to do is store a description of what the file does, it would need to be added the first time a file is added to SVN.  I can't find any such field through TortoiseSVN.

If I can't do this in Subversion it means using a spreadsheet!

Comment: "What I need to do is store a description of what the file does" IMHO this should be part of the external documentation of your system, not integrated into the VCS history. Where will this content go when/if you switch to another VCS?

Comment: It does eventually form part of the external documentation, but we were hoping to use SVN to generate it initially.

Comment: you need smarter clients.

Comment: @thekbb far too much paperwork for my liking sometimes

Comment: IME, most things that are labeled as "eventually it will be part of the primary documentation" never get there. Start it out right. Document your system *while* you're building it - not after. Because the documentation at the end is *always* the easiest thing to cut for time/budget constraints. Or worse, you'll forget why that widget was added 3 months later.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do. Devs input the data as they work then I can export it all at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add your own custom SVN property to each file:

> svn propset filedescription 'This file describes the functionality of Foo' src/Foo.cs

Then, you could write a tool that reads this property for each file and constructs the documentation for you, using:

> svn propget filedescription src/Foo.cs

In TortoiseSVN: right-click the file in the checkout `->` **TortoiseSVN** `->` **Properties**.

[image: TortoiseSVN context menu]

Then, **New...** `->` **Advanced**, and in the **Add Properties** window, add your custom property:

[image: Adding a custom property to Foo.cs]

Result:

[image: Sample result]

Hope this helps.

Comment: and you can add a pre-commit hook to ensure that the property is present for all newly added files.

Comment: is there a way to automatically add the custom property to every file automatically?  I don't want to have to rely upon people remembering to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to automatically add the custom property to every file automatically? I don't want to have to rely upon people remembering to do this.

Yes and no...

You can create a auto-properties in your personal Subversion configuration. This will automatically crate a property on a particular file when added by that user. However, that is not enforceable.

My [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) can enforce the user of a particular property.

```
[property All files must have a site:description property on them]
match = .*
property = site:description
value = .+
type = regex
```

This will prevent someone from committing a file that doesn't have the property `site:description` set on it.

You use this hook, ***and*** let users know how they can [setup auto-properties in their Subversion configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto). The pre-commit hook will act as a gentle reminder that the developer needs to setup the auto-property setting in their Subversion configuration.

(By the way, my hook can also verify that there is a commit description, and can even verify the description's format too).

---

### Now to get to the important point...

> I have configured a pre-commit hook to force developers to add a description of why a file changed when they are trying to commit.

Are you encouraging your developers to commit file-by-file?

Subversion uses *change sets*. For example, I might add a new feature by changing a half dozen files. This should be committed in one single commit. And, the commit message is for all 6 of those files.

Commit messages can be multiple lines long, and many developers to make them that way because they want to describe the change made to each file. That's fine. What I insist upon is the general reason for the change and usually relating back to a specific Issue ID in our issue tracking system. I want to see "BUG-1233: Passwords are now stored as encoded strings and no longer as clear text". 23 files may have been changed, and two files were deleted, and four new files were added, but all of these changes were for this one fix, and that's what I want to see. The developer can go into the each of the 29 file changes in detail and make the commit message 60+ lines long. I just want to see the change reason relating back to a particular feature or bug.

This way, I can use commit messages to see what issues were addressed in our code, and I can back out a change if it is causing problems during testing.

> Is there a way to automatically add the custom property to every file automatically? I don't want to have to rely upon people remembering to do this.

You force your developers to describe each file's purpose, and then wan to give them a way to generate a default description automatically? You know that the developers will simply use the default description and never change it? Right?

---

#### Additional Answer

There is a way in TortoiseSVN to create a client side hook. I never did this, but it might be possible for users to create a client side hook to bring up a dialog box, so they can enter the file's description.

This would only work for Tortoise, and only on that particular machine. However, you can combine it with my pre-commit hook, and you show developers how to create the Tortoise client side hook (which executes before the server's pre-commit hook). This way, their TortoiseSVN hook will help them fill in the descriptions, and my server pre-commit hook will make sure that they don.

Comment: Our developers commit files as "sets" too. Each commit relates to a specific change (bug fix, change request, etc).

Comment: The file description describes what the files does.  The commit comment describes why the file was changed.  It would be 2 different things with no default values hopefully.

Comment: The whole reason for this is to ultimately produce a report at the end of the project where you can say things like "myfile.js provides the rotating image banner gallery functionality on the homepage".  At the moment we have to go through all the files manually at the end of a project to come up with this information.

Comment: See my additional answer above.

Comment: For TSVN's client-side hooks and hooks in common: 1) in TSVN 1.8.* client-hooks can be shared on per-repository basis 2) It's **strongly not-recommended** to change transaction-data in pre-* hooks (and properties **are** part of transaction)